# Proving that $\max_{\|M\|_{rs}\leq 1,\ \|b\|_s\leq 1} \|A^{-1}(Mc-b) \|_r \geq \|A^{-1}\|_{sr}(\|c\|_r+1) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

In fact, what I really want to prove is the equality. The another inequality is already proven, but this one I'm not able to prove. Fix an invertible matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I need to prove the following inequality.

$$\max_{\|M\|_{rs}\leq 1,\ \|b\|_s\leq 1} \|A^{-1}(Mc-b) \|_r \geq \|A^{-1}\|_{sr}(\|c\|_r+1) $$

$r,s$ are positive integers and $\|\cdot\|_{rs}$ is the [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) induced by the [norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) $\|\cdot\|_r$ and $\|\cdot\|_s$.

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT:** Ok, I have an answer and I'm very grateful for it. But what I should have said is that I want a direct proof. Is it possible to exhibit $M$ and $b$ in order to get an equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that, for all $ \ M \in \overline{B_{rs} ( 0 , 1 )} \ $ and for all $ \ b \in \overline{B_s (0,1)} \ $, we have that $$|A^{-1}| \cdot (|c| + 1) < | A^{-1} (Mc - b) | \ . $$ So, for all $ \ M \in \overline{B_{rs} ( 0 , 1 )} \ $ and for all $ \ b \in \overline{B_s (0,1)} \ , $ one has $$|A^{-1}| \cdot (|c| + 1) < | A^{-1} (Mc - b) | \leqslant |A^{-1}| \cdot |Mc - b| =$$ $$= |A^{-1}| \cdot |Mc + (-b)| \leqslant |A^{-1}| \cdot (|Mc| + |-b|) = |A^{-1}| \cdot (|Mc| + |b|) \ . $$ Take $ \ M= id_{\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \ \ $ and $ \ b = (1,0,0,...,0) \ $ to get a contradiction.